# Динамическое увеличение ширины блока div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть тег `div` с элементом `h1` внутри. Текст внутри `h1` добавялется динамически из формы. По умолчанию, ширина блока `div` составляет `300рх`, а размер текста `60рх`. Если кол-во символов в одном слове вмещается в эту ширину, то при переносе слов, блок увеличивается в высоту.
 Задача в том, чтобы блок `div` расширялся в ширину, когда кол-во символов в одном слове не вмещается в эти `300рх`.
 Можно ли это сделать с помощью лишь `CSS` или же только при помощи `JS`?

Comment: использовать не width, a min-width ?

Comment: в таком случае div растягивается на весь экран

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что вот так можно сделать

```css
div {display: inline-block;background-color:red;color:white;min-width:300px;}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Этот текст не вместился в 300px</h1>
</div>
```